# How to give input parameter to the concourse pipeline on the pipeline page and trigger the job similar to jenkins

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-fly

I would like to know if it is possible to give inputs to a concourse pipeline from the UI.
I know we can add input details to a git repo and read from the repo, but for every tiny input I need to do a code commit.
For this scenario is Jenkins better than concourse?

I tried searching in the internet to find if it is possible to give inputs to the concourse pipeline, but I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual inputs via UI are not a thing in Concourse.

FWIW: When I need frequent inputs and want to avoid git commits for that purpose, I use an [s3 resource](https://github.com/concourse/s3-resource) versioned file in my pipeline as an input, for example with a `send_input.sh` script like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1" > /tmp/input.txt
aws s3 cp /tmp/input.txt s3://my-bucket/my-concourse-resource-file.txt
```

and then

```
./send_input.sh "this is my input"
```

then the pipeline picks it up and uses it in my workflow.